# Parametrizing a set of lines from a parametrization of a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a parametrization $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$ of a curve, can one similarly parametrize the set of lines that go through the origin and a point on the curve? I wonder if this is impossible...

If it is possible, I wonder how one can no such a thing "on sight".

Comment: I'm thinking maybe we can have $(\lambda,t)\mapsto\lambda\cdot \gamma(t)$ be a parametrization by $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x-t}{x-0}=\frac{y-t^2}{y-0}=\frac{z-t^3}{z-0}=u\text{ (say)}$$

So that $x-t=ux,x=\frac t{1-u}$

Similarly, $y=\frac {t^2}{1-u},z=\frac {t^3}{1-u}$

Clearly, $u\ne1$ as $u=1\implies t=0$

Comment: Interesting. Is this equivalent to my commented-try somehow?

Comment: @WouterZeldenthuis, could you please elaborate your point. I needed one more parameter $u$

Comment: Shouldn't this look like a double cone? Therefore a parametrization should need two variables. My map above seems to work, since $\gamma(t)$ gives you a point on the curve, and by varying $\lambda$ you can get any point on the line going through the origin and that point.